# String formatting with unicode characters using Lua

Tags: lua, string.format, unicode-string

I trying to align string with unicode characters.
But it doesn't works.
Spaces is not correct. :( 
Lua's version is 5.1.
What is the problem?

```
local t = 
{
    "character",
    "루아",           -- korean
    "abc감사합니다123", -- korean
    "ab23",
    "lua is funny",
    "ㅇㅅㅇ",
    "美國大將",         --chinese
    "qwert-54321",
};

for k, v in pairs(t) do
    print(string.format("%30s", v));
end


result:----------------------------------------------
                     character  
                        루아  
          abc감사합니다123   
                          ab23  
                  lua is funny  
                      ㅇㅅㅇ   
                   美國大將 
                   qwert-54321
```

Comment: Formatting Unicode characters can be tricky because not only does each character take a variable number of bytes when encoded, but they also use up a variable number of columns when displayed. Doing a quick search on Luarocks, the [wcwidth](https://luarocks.org/modules/aperezdc/wcwidth) library looks like it is relevant for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
function utf8format(fmt, ...)
   local args, strings, pos = {...}, {}, 0
   for spec in fmt:gmatch'%%.-([%a%%])' do
      pos = pos + 1
      local s = args[pos]
      if spec == 's' and type(s) == 'string' and s ~= '' then
         table.insert(strings, s)
         args[pos] = '\1'..('\2'):rep(#s:gsub("[\128-\191]", "")-1)
      end
   end
   return (fmt:format((table.unpack or unpack)(args))
      :gsub('\1\2*', function() return table.remove(strings, 1) end)
   )
end

local t =
{
   "character",
   "루아",           -- korean
   "abc감사합니다123", -- korean
   "ab23",
   "lua is funny",
   "ㅇㅅㅇ",
   "美國大將",         --chinese
   "qwert-54321",
   "∞"
};

for k, v in pairs(t) do
   print(utf8format("%30s", v));
end
```

But there is another problem: on most fonts korean and chinese symbols are wider than latin letters.

Comment: For anyone wondering: the main trick here is using `#s:gsub("[\128-\191]", "")` to get the number of code-points in a utf-8 string.
the gsub removes all characters between 128 and 191, which leaves 1 byte per utf-8 sequence, no matter how many bytes it started as. Every sequence starts with either a character < 128 (ascii), or a character ≥ 192, followed by 1-3 more bytes which are all between 128 and 191

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII strings are all formatted correctly, while the non-ASCII strings are not.

The reason is because, the length of the strings are counted with their number of bytes. For instance, with UTF-8 encodings,

```
print(string.len("美國大將"))  -- 12
print(string.len("루아"))      -- 6
```

So `%s` in `string.format` treat these two strings as if their width is 12 / 6.

Comment: Thanks Yu. understood. :D